# Will the dd-wrt Big build run on my Linksys WRT54GL?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys WRT54GL access point acting as a NAT router, with the inside network being my house's wireless and the outside network being a point-to-point link to my DSL gateway. My ISP is Telmex (Prodigy Infinitum).

Yesterday, after spending like 2 hours troubleshooting a failing internet which turned out to be because the access point bugged out and stopped forwarding packets (solved with a 30-30-30 reset), I decided I need to install dd-wrt on my AP to see if it will be more stable. Judging from [the feature list for the different builds](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#Notes), I think the Big build will be good for my case because I intend to use OpenVPN and IPv6 in the future. The feature list says the Big builds are for Broadcom devices, which is what the WRT54GL is. However, [the instruction page](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54GL) does not mention any such thing about the Big build running successfully, all it says is that flashing a Mega build will brick my router and that I should flash first a Micro build, then a Standard, VOIP or VPN build.

So, given that there is no mention of Big builds of dd-wrt running on WRT54GL APs, does anyone here have any experience with running this kind of build?

Comment: According to the [Router's page](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) on the site it does not look like the Big Build is supported.

Comment: I'd also note that there's three, maybe 4 varients of the WRT54GL IIRC. The thing you need to look at is the amount of flash storage in your specific varient. I never did find out how to get ipv6 on mine, it currently runs as an ap behind a newer router that does ipv6rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the following page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54GL) the WRT54GL only has 4MB of flash memory.  The Big Build [requires 8MB according to note 4](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#Notes).  The WRT54GL will not run the Big Build.

Comment: Wow, good thing I asked before bricking my access point. I share it with my family so I have to manage it like a production system. Thanks for the answer. Now... time to choose between OpenVPN or IPv6, only one of them...

Comment: honestly on a home network IPv6 would be a lower priority in my opinion.  IPv4 has more than ample address space unless you have a ridiculously massive home network...  Good luck!